# Maps Automation possible with Seetest?

Tags: automated-testing, android, ios, mobile-automation, seetest

Just wanted to know if it is possible to automate if a map is loading in an androin/ios app using Seetest. I write automation tests for android/ios apps.

Thanks,
kalyan

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can automate MAP using SEETEST

[Pinch Command Refrence](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Pinch)

Go through all the commands for reference - [SeeTest Commands](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Object+Commands)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, type of map, etc...

But as SeeTest has a fallback in interacting with images it should be able to automate anything on the screen if you could do it manually.

[SeeTest has a 30day trail](https://experitest.com/download/seetestautomation/), so just try it out with your application.